# chi-squared for two rasters in R

Tags: raster, r, comparison

I am kind of new with statistics. I have two raster with categorical values and I want to get chi-square. How can I do this using R? Rasters have the same region and  same resolution. Is chi-square the right choice for the computation of variance by ranks?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "computation of variance by ranks"?  That seems almost wholly unrelated to a chi-squared statistic.

Comment: I want to see whether distributions of categorical variables differ from one another. I have the two rasters (independent and not independent variable). Basically I want to see the differences between them.

Comment: The chi-square test, as usually applied, does not address that question: it assesses whether the distributions are *independent.*  Moreover, because data in individual cells in rasters are usually strongly interdependent, the p-value from just about any test will be invalid. How to proceed depends on what these data mean, how they were measured, how they were converted to raster representation, and what you really want to find out.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a question not so related to GIS, that is since you are treating the raster as a "list" (or a vector) of values. Anyhow you can use the following workflow in R:
Assume you have raster objects called r1 and r2.

Extract values of r1 and r2 cells to vectors

```
r1Vals <- getValues(r1)
r2Vals <- getValues(r2)
```

Convert values to factor (categorical)

```
r1Vals <- as.factor(r1Vals)
r2Vals <- as.factor(r2Vals)
```

Preforms Pearson's chi-square test

```
chisq(r1,r2)
```

I suggest further reading on the R functions: [getValues](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/getValues) of the raster package; [chisq](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/chisq.test.html) of the stats package; and the [factor](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/factor.html) object from the base package.

In addition - it is recommended to get help about the right statistical test and its validity to your data in [Cross-Validate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) forum.