# Chi-square between rasters

Tags: raster, r, statistics, land-cover, soil

I have **two rasters** (both with 10 m * 10 m resolution, for an area of approx. 1 000 km2) with the following variables. Both are categorical.

A) Habitat type with 9 different classes.

B) Soil moisture in 3 classes.

I would like to test the **association** between habitat type (A) and soil moisture (B).

Would a **chi-square test** be suitable to test for positive or negative association between habitat types and soil moisture classes?

In [chi-squared for two rasters in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140200) there is a comment that *“data in individual cells in rasters are usually strongly interdependent, the p-value from just about any test will be invalid”*. I do not fully understand that comment.

I am using R for my analysis.

Comment: How do you want to parameterise "association"? You've got 9 Habitats and 3 Soils, so 27 parameters can fully parameterise the association which you can estimate from counts in the rasters. This is then like fitting a straight line through 2 points - there's no stochasticity and no uncertainty and no statistical test to do - the data is the whole truth, and if P(H1->S2) > P(H1->S3) then H1 is more associated with S2 than S3. Unless you can specify some uncertainty on your data, or fewer parameters in your model, that's as good as it gets.

Comment: Please decide whether it is QGIS, R or ArcMap that you wish to ask about in this particular question.

Comment: I adjusted accordingly - R is the only one remaining.